# reset the color of a previously pressed button after another button is pressed in custom keyboard in android

Tags: android

I have a situation.I have created a custom keyboard. In which i have to add functionality like when user click on a button, button color will change and when user click on next button on the keyboard the color of previous button should be reset and the color of currently pressed button should be change.

```
here is the my XML code

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/hebrwKeyboardView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_below="@+id/xsubLayout"
     android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#252625"
     android:visibility="visible" android:layout_height="180sp">
     <TableLayout 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="200sp"
     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:clipChildren="true">
     <TableLayout 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="200sp"
     android:padding="0sp">
     <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="0sp">
     <LinearLayout android:baselineAligned="true"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="45sp"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
     <Button android:id="@+id/xQ" android:layout_width="30sp"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Q"
     android:textColor="#000" android:tag="Q" android:padding="0sp"
     android:textStyle="bold"  android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"/>
     <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xW"
     android:layout_width="30sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:padding="0sp" android:textColor="#000" android:tag="W"
     android:text="W" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_gravity="left" />
     <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xE"
     android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_width="30sp"
     android:padding="0sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:text="E" android:tag="E" android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textColor="#000" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
     <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xR"
     android:layout_width="30sp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="R" android:tag="R"
     android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:ellipsize="marquee" />
     <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xT"
     android:layout_width="33sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:text="T"
     android:tag="T" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold"
     android:ellipsize="marquee" />
     <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xY"
     android:layout_width="33sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:tag="y" android:layout_gravity="center" android:text="Y"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:textColor="#000"
     android:textStyle="bold" android:ellipsize="marquee" />
     <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xU"
     android:layout_width="33sp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="U" android:tag="U"
     android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:ellipsize="marquee" />
     <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xI"
     android:layout_width="33sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:text="I" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:tag="I"
     android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:ellipsize="marquee" />
     <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xO"
     android:layout_width="33sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:text="O" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:tag="O"
     android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:ellipsize="marquee" />
     <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xP"
     android:layout_width="33sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="P"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:tag="P"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:ellipsize="marquee" />
     </LinearLayout>
     </TableRow>
     <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="45sp">
     <Button android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
     android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xA"
     android:layout_width="30sp" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:tag="A" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|center"
     android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="A"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
     </LinearLayout>
     </TableRow>
     </TableLayout>
     </TableLayout>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: first reset all button, then change the color of new one.

Comment: can u please tell me how can i reset all button. because i have plenty of button in custom keyboard

Comment: how about using a loop :)

Comment: post an answer how you did it.. :) and accept it.. it would help others !

Comment: ok no problem :) here is my code
make a function name reset() and call it from onClick method.
code for reset is here
        public void reset(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 for(int i=0; i<mB.length; i++)
 {
           mB[i].setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default); 
 }
  
 }

Comment: and how to call it from on click here is the code
        @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

        
        reset(v);
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonselector);

Comment: It will reset all the buttons

Comment: put this in the answer box below, or should I put it. !

Answer (score 1):

Create a function named `reset()` and call it from onClick method.

```
public void reset(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
for(int i=0; i<mB.length; i++) {
 mB[i].setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
     }
 }
```

call it from a button click as

```
@Override public void onClick(View v) { 
reset(v); 
v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonselector); 
}
```